# For loop error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to run a for loop as part of a hypothesis function for a linear regression in Matlab, however am struggling to get it to run. Below is the function:

```
function hypothesis = calculate_hypothesis(X, theta, training_example)

%CALCULATE_HYPOTHESIS This calculates the hypothesis for a given X,
%theta and specified training example

hypothesis = 0; 
for training_example = 1:size(X,1)
    hypothesis = theta'.*X(training_example,:) + hypothesis
end 

end
```

`X` is a 47x3 matrix (3 variables in the linear regression equation, with 47 examples), and `theta` is a 1x3 matrix representing the weights for the variables. Note that the objective here is to 'learn' the correct weights for the equation from the 47 examples using gradient descent, but I'm comfortable with the methodology for this. What I'm having trouble with is getting the matlab code to run for the hypothesis equation. The error I get is

`Not enough input arguments. Error in calculate_hypothesis (line 5) for training_example = 1:size(X,1)`

Am new to Matlab, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show the call for your function? Do you pass arguments?

Comment: why do you specify the training data set as an input argument and use the same variable name for the for loop? Either you want to use one specific data set or use all? So what is it really what you want to do? Please add an example of the desired input/output of your function (see: [ask])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to pass

```
training_example
```

as a parameter to your function

```
calculate_hypothesis(X, theta, training_example)
```

Because whatever value you pass will be overwritten by the for loop, which applies new values to training_example with every iteration.
I guess you are only calling calculate_hypothesis() with X and theta and thus get the error "not enough input arguments".

Try changing

```
calculate_hypothesis(X, theta, training_example)
```

to

```
calculate_hypothesis(X, theta)
```

Comment: It is interesting that you advice to take this argument away, as this is the specified training data set on which the function "learns". Wouldn`t it be better to change the variable of the for-loop or rather get ride of the for-loop instead? As it is unclear you should have first asked in a comment what the real goal of the for-loop is?

Comment: Thr argument is used only once in the code as an index of X and thus it is pretty obvious to me, that the one usage of training_example is meant to be the iterating variable of the for loop rather than any training data. As there is only this one single usage of training_example, I think there was no confusion of variable names but the asker must have thought he has to pass all variables he is using in the function. Of course that is an assumption, but I think it is a plausible one.

Comment: Too add some context, this is a university problem, and the 'skeleton' of the function was given to us, now I believe training_example actually refers to a row in X, so my logic was to use training_example as an index for each row and then loop through. It seems straight forward enough but doesn't seem to work. I can't spot any mistakes in the code which I am using

Comment: When removing the argument from the function as described in my answer above, you should not get the "not enough input arguments" error anymore. This might not solve your university task, which is unknown to me, but it should solve the problem of the "not enough input arguments" error your original question was about. Can you please refer to my solution, and tell whether it helps?